# C++ Qualification conversions - constness and templates

Tags: c++

In the code below, I'm trying to figure out why the compiler (msdev c++ 2010 and Comeau) does not consider the return type of the non specialized template get function to be const. I would expect CASE #2 (see code snipet) to NOT compile, yet it does. Any ideas or links?

Thank you, regu

```
template < typename T >
struct constness
{
  T value;
  constness() : value(0) {}
  const T &get() { return value; }
};

template < typename T >
struct constness< T * >
{
   T * const value;
   constness() : value(0) {}
   const T * const &get() { return value; }
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
  // Uses specialized
  constness< double * > wConstness;
  const_cast< double * & >(wConstness.value) = new double(1);
  *wConstness.get() = 12.0; // CASE #1 doesn't compile

  // Uses non specialized 
  constness< double * const > wConstness2;
  const_cast< double * & >(wConstness2.value) = new double(1);
  *wConstness2.get() = 12.0; // CASE #2 compiles, allowing modification of 
                             // value pointed by wConstness2.value

  return 0;
};
```

Comment: `const_cast< double * >(wConstness2.value) = new double(1);` is wrong:  the target type of the cast needs to be `double*&` in order to have an lvalue to which you can assign.

Comment: doh! ... getting too late here :D

Answer (score 3):

You instantiate `constness` with `T` = `double * const` (a const-qualified pointer to a non-const-qualified `double`).

In `const T& get()`, the `const` applies to the whole `T`.  If `T` was `int*`, then `const T` would be `int* const`, not `const int*`.  So in your specific case, the `const` has no effect because `T` is already const-qualified (it is a `double* const`).

When you have a typename like `T`, adding `const` or `volatile` to the typename always applies at the top level regardless of what the type is.  So, `const T` and `T const` are always the same, regardless what `T` is.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, unfortunately means my design won't work :D